# Initialts algorithm c++11

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to write a code which prints out an initials of a string.
But I have a problem in one case, where those  names are with more than one 
white-space characters.And I came up with an idea to delete those white-spaces characters that aren't necessary  and leave only one  white space,but I'm not yet confident in strings and could somebody tell me what I should do ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

std::string initials(const std::string &w )
{
    char space = ' ';
    std::string a;
    a.push_back(w[0]);
    for (int i = 0; i < w.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (w[i] == space )
        {
            a.push_back(w[i+1]);


        }

    }
    return a;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout<<  initials(std::string("Julian     Rodriguez        Antonio "))<<std::endl;

}
```

Comment: Do you want to build a function ? or using the help of build in functions.

Comment: Build a function which prints out  initials  with  help of build in functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to  keep in memory the information if last character was a space or not..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

std::string initials(const std::string &w) {
    char space = ' ';
    std::string a;
    int mode = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < w.size(); ++i) {
        if (w[i] == space) {
            mode = 0;
        } else {
            if (mode == 0) a.push_back(w[i]);
            mode = 1;
        }
    }
    return a;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout<<  initials(std::string(" Julian     Rodriguez        Antonio "))<<std::endl;
}
```

**EDIT**: thanks to a suggestion of Pete Becker, here is a clearer implementation.

```
std::string initials(const std::string &w) {
    char space = ' ';
    std::string a;
    bool skipping_spaces = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < w.size(); ++i) {
        if (w[i] == space) {
            skipping_spaces = true;
        } else {
            if (skipping_spaces) a.push_back(w[i]);
            skipping_spaces = false;
        }
    }
    return a;
}
```

Comment: I mean its great what u wrote there but output should be  : JRA     in what I'm  trying to do

Comment: Okay , Thank you very much. <3

Comment: Even better: change the name of `mode` to `skipping_spaces`, change those `0`s `true`s, and change those `1`s to `false`s. Then `if (mode == 0)` becomes `if (skipping_spaces)`, which is much clearer. +1.